# Editing multiple external links on Excel with a macro

Tags: vba, excel, edit

My VBA knowledge isn't immaculate so apologies in advance. Every month I've got to edit the links in my files to change the reference month (eg: Jul -xxxxx to Aug  -xxxxx)

I've got a macro the following to list the external links on a sheet (eg A1:A6)

```
Sub Display_Links()
'
' Display_Links Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
Dim aLinks As Variant
Dim i As Integer
aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(aLinks)
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = aLinks(i)
'       ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0), Address:=ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0)
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

where I then copy and paste that range onto B1:B6, and find and replace the month (from Jul to Aug), so I have the new links I need on the sheet.

Then I have the following macro:

```
Sub Linkupdate()

ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Range("A1").Text, _
    Range("B1").Text, xlExcelLinks

End Sub
```

With this I can change each link, but how do I define the whole range (a1:a6) to be updated with (b1:b6)?

Many thanks!

TL;DR - I'm trying edit multiple links on a WB without using the edit links function as the only change I need to do is change the month (eg: Jul -xxxxx to Aug -xxxxx)

Comment: are you currently typing in the cells and launching `linkupdate()` one by one but you are trying to get it so that you dont have to?

Comment: Hi @ShanayL, exactly! What i'm currently doing isn't much of an upgrade from the default edit links process, hence I'm looking to see if I can change a whole range of links at once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming what you have currently works you just want it to loop on it own. Your are going to have to do a loop so that excel knows how many cells to capture.

Something like:

```
Sub Linkupdate() 
    Dim Row As Integer

    Row = 1
    LastRow = Worksheets("WorksheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Do while Row <= LastRow
      ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Range("A" & row).Text, _
      Range("B" & row).Text, xlExcelLinks
      Row = Row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ShanayL, this is exactly what I wanted!!